# Android errors when building for Android for first time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We have a Xamarin project which we've been developing with iOS for quite some time. Obviously, it was working fine on iOS. I've been updating Android as well when I updated iOS. We're currently on `Xamarin.Android 7.1.0.41` using `Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25424.00 Update 3` using `Xamarin 4.3.0.784`. I was able to get the Android SDK installed, and it opens when I go to `Tools > Android > SDK Manager`.

I then installed the items that Xamarin tells you to install here: [Manual Installation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/)

Which included:

- Android SDK Tools (25.2.5)
- Android SDK Platform-tools (25.0.4)
- Android SDK Build Tools (25.0.2)

I also went further and installed:

- Google Play Services (39)
- Google Repository (45)
- Android Support Repository (46)

Every time I try to build though, I get the following errors:

> C:**\XamarinMobile\XamarinMobile\XamarinMobile.Android\obj\Debug\resourcecache\56963C70904301C7982EF8068B25EDB4\res\values\wallet_attrs.xml(8):
>   error APT0000: Attribute "theme" already defined with incompatible
>   format.

and

> C:**\XamarinMobile\XamarinMobile\XamarinMobile.Android\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B27B697E5C2AF4461D5E802284ECB7E8\res\values\values.xml(132):
>   error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:elevation'.

This errors point to specific files in the Android solution, I've supplied the screenshots:

[image: AndroidErrors]

Any ideas? If you need any more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't remember bad it could be a problem caused by an incompatibility between support libraries and the Android SDK.

For instance I had a similar problem when I updated Android SDK to 24 (7.0) but I couldn't update the support libraries from 23.x to 24 because of problem with the Multidex. If you don't need the SDK 25 I would try to use the 24 with 24 or 25 of support libraries version.